# Can I use a Windows .Net app with Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm a little confused by all the chat about Docker, and how it fits into the virtualisation world. So here's a straight question: can I package up a .Net application (that normally runs on Windows 7 etc) to run in a Docker container, and then  execute it on 'any' host supporting Docker?

TIA.

Comment: If you mean by .NET app a regular .NET 4.6 (or lower) web application, then YES, you can package it up and run it with Mono in a Docker container. For example the [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) framework was built from day 1 with the idea to be cross platform and you can (and people do) run a .NET web application in Docker containers with it. See [Running NancyFx in a Docker container, a beginner's guide to build and run .NET applications in Docker](http://dusted.codes/running-nancyfx-in-a-docker-container-a-beginners-guide-to-build-and-run-dotnet-applications-in-docker) for more information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not today.  In future, Microsoft and Docker have [announced](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/15/new-windows-server-containers-and-azure-support-for-docker/) that you there will be a Windows version of Docker.

Edit: [newer info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/containers_welcome)

Note that the base platform and OS have to match - i.e. today you can run ARM Linux containers on ARM Linux and x64 Linux containers on x64 Linux, but you can't mix and match.  When Windows is added, the pattern will be the same - you will be able to run Windows containers on Windows OS, but not on Linux.  Not without an extra layer of virtualization (like VirtualBox, VMWare, etc).

Edit: respect to the [Wine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27129913/448734) answer, which I hadn't considered.  It sort-of fits as "an extra layer of virtualization", but at the OS API level not the hardware level.  And somewhat restricted in scope of .Net programs supported.

In a similar vein, you might be able to run your .Net code in Docker using [Mono](https://github.com/mono/docker).

Comment: That answers the question. I thought as much but it wasn't quite clear to me (that is, everything I read neither ruled it in nor ruled it out). So behind the hype it's not quite the silver bullet I hoped for. :-(

Comment: It often turns out there is no actual magic in a software product :-)

Answer (score 4):

Docker builds on Linux. The only way to get the .Net app run in Docker is by using Mono for Linux.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out there is an official microsoft repository on the Hub, with an asp.net image which runs on Mono: https://registry.hub.docker.com/repos/microsoft/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you install wine and .NET, here is an example of such a Dockerfile

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/justmoon/wix/dockerfile/

extract

```
# Install .NET Framework 4.0
```

RUN wine wineboot && xvfb-run winetricks --unattended dotnet40 corefonts

Comment: Another example, if you want to test your PowerShell skills, use the following Dockerfile https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/solarkennedy/powershell/dockerfile/

Answer (score 3):

This maybe very out of date question, but I think it need a update. Yes you can use docker with .net / .net core and will fully support in Visual Studio 2017.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2016/172

The be no need to use WINE or Mono.

Answer (score 1):

below is example dockerfile to run .net 4.5 app

```
FROM microsoft/iis

RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET"]
RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45"]

ADD publisedDir/ c:\\website

EXPOSE 8081

RUN powershell New-Website -Name 'websiteName' -Port 8081 -PhysicalPath 'c:\website' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'

ENTRYPOINT powershell
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but still if it helps anyone.
Yes we can run .Net apps on Docker as docker is now supported with Windows natively. But first you have to check your windows version, your windows build must be 14393.233 or greater. Download Docker 1.13.0 or later and then you can easily run a .Net App. 
[This repository](https://github.com/kahootali/ASP.Net-App-for-Windows-Containers) 
walks through running a sample .Net App.