# Running .Net on Docker

Tags: .net, docker

Since [Microsoft made .Net cross platform](http://news.microsoft.com/2014/11/12/microsoft-takes-net-open-source-and-cross-platform-adds-new-development-capabilities-with-visual-studio-2015-net-2015-and-visual-studio-online/)
Is it possible to package and run .Net applications as docker packages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a Windows .Net app with Docker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128751/can-i-use-a-windows-net-app-with-docker)

Comment: The question and answers there don't take into account .Net is now cross platform.

Comment: you can often  (not always) use wine and launch a Windows .exe in a container. The Dockerfile in this link https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1809831 does among other things `RUN /usr/bin/xvfb-run -s -noreset -a winetricks -q --unattended vcrun2010 dotnet40 gdiplus comctl32 ie8` so installs dotnet40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find lots of examples by googling. Like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/14/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit more information here...

Yes it is possible, but not only since ASP.NET Core 1.0 and the new cross platform libaries.

The new ASP.NET Core is supported to run either via the new CoreCLR or Mono on Linux and Mac. Before ASP.NET Core you could run on Mono as well. For example the [NancyFx framework](http://nancyfx.org/) was built with the idea to run on Mono.

Here is an example how you can run a regular .NET 4.6 (or lower) application with the Nancy framework in a Docker container:

[Running NancyFx in a Docker container, a beginner's guide to build and run .NET applications in Docker](http://dusted.codes/running-nancyfx-in-a-docker-container-a-beginners-guide-to-build-and-run-dotnet-applications-in-docker)